# How can I use man without less?

Tags: man, less

By default, `man` uses `less` to output text. How can I tell it to just output to stdout? My terminal emulator has a scroll bar and search function and I want to use those instead of the arrow keys.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Actually it uses whatever is specified in the `MANPAGER` or the `PAGER` environment variable.

Depending on your `man` implementation and version there could be also a command line switch to specify the pager.

With the [man-db](http://nongnu.org/man-db/) implementation I use all the below ways work:

```
MANPAGER=cat man man

PAGER=cat man man

MANOPT='-P cat' man man

man -P cat man
```

To set it permanently, just add it to your `~/.bashrc` (or other initialization file used by your shell):

```
export MANPAGER=cat
```

That works with some older `man` implementations too, while `MANOPT` is man-db specific:

```
export MANOPT='-P cat'
```

(Better do not set `PAGER` that way. That one is used by many other applications too.)

There could be also a global configuration file. man-db has `/etc/man_db.conf` or `/etc/manpath.config`. There you can set:

```
DEFINE    pager    cat
```

But unfortunately that is taken in consideration only if neither `MANPAGER` nor `PAGER` is set.

Comment: Good answer.  Re: `~/.bashrc`, You could also wrap the export in a conditional so it only sets the pager if it's the appropriate terminal/emulator: `if [ "x$TERM" = "xxterm" ]; then export MANPAGER=cat; fi`; obviously replace `xterm` with the appropriate emulator.

Comment: Actually, it's good and by design that manpath.config is taken into account later. Both PAGER and MANPAGER are user level, where the config file is system level. If system level would take precedence then users could not override at all.

Comment: @PauldeVrieze, you are right on `MANPAGER`. I used the “unfortunately” word for the fact that the behavior also applies to `PAGER`, which is a _generic_ setting (used by many tools) and I would prefer it to not override a _specific_ setting (used by only one tool), even if that one is system level.

Comment: If you want to override a specific setting for a single tool you can always do so by creating an alias, a shell function or a wrapper script. Either of those would amount to: `PAGER=cat man`, for example: `alias man='PAGER=cat MANPAGER=cat man'`

Answer (score 8):

Simply pipe the output of `man` to `cat`?

```
man ls | cat   # useful use of cat
```

Comment: Note that depending on the `man` implementation, that either 1) rises error, 2) displays troff format codes in the terminal, 3) removes all formatting, 4) works as expected.

Comment: I've never seen it do other than 4.

Comment: @KeithThompson macOS's `man` seems to use the pager set in `MANPAGER` even when the output is a file or a pipe. And if the pager is `less`, then it's all good because `less` behaves like `cat` when output is a pipe... But if you use something else (like Vim, which I use), then it's not so good.

Answer (score 3):

Try these commands to generate man output without a pager.

- `man ls | cat`   (generated fixed width)
- `man -P cat ls`  (generated variable width)

I was on a GNU linux system

Answer (score 1):

Another angle: Similar to Tony's answer.

You can also redirect man output into a file and view it with your favorite text editor or even add bookmarks, comments, etc. to it.

```
man bash  > bashman.txt
```

I have a copy of the bash man page as well as just the sections on bash flow control and bash test flags saved as text files in my bin directory so I can load them right into my text editor (kate) for reference while I'm writing bash scripts.

---

Warning: depending on your system and the man page, the above command may result in formatting information and control characters in the file.

To avoid this, do as suggested in `LESS='+/^TIPS' man man`:

```
To  get a  plain  text  version  of a man page, without backspaces and
underscores, try

  # man foo | col -b > foo.mantxt
```

Comment: @Wildcard - Thanks. I didn't know about that.