# Why are man pages blank for non-root users?

Tags: rhel, man

. . . And how can I fix that?  :-)  I'm running RHEL 5 and when I try to view man pages as a regular user, they are blank.  I've tried `man man > manman.txt; cat manman.txt` and there is no output, i.e., the file has no length.  I try `sudo man man` and I see beautiful man page output.

I've looked at the permissions under /usr/share/man and they look okay.  The directories are all o+rwx and the files are o+r.

I've tried . . .

```
[me@host01 ~]$ sudo man -w man
/usr/share/man/en/man1/man.1.gz
[me@host01 ~]$ man /usr/share/man/en/man1/man.1.gz
```

. . . and that's blank also.

Comment: Does e.g. `man su` work for you?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Nope.  That's blank also.

Comment: As a non-root user, what does `zcat /usr/share/man/en/man1/man.1.gz` produce? A man page or an error message?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That produces a man page.

Comment: Sounds like you've messed up the environment variables for the pager that `man` uses to display its contents. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23394/how-can-i-use-man-without-less

Comment: I agree with slm. Try `man -M /usr/share/man/en/man1 man` and see if that works. If it does, then your `MANPATH` isn't properly defined for your regular user.

Comment: Can you share some debugging information? E.g. pasting the output of `man -d man` may shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to give this one to my co-worker who discovered that the permissions on `/tmp` were incorrect:

```
[user@host01 ~]$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 28 18:44 /tmp

And we know they should be set with 1777:
[root@host01 ~]# ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 7 root root 4096 Jul 28 18:44 /tmp

Found this out when I tried to run nroff.
[user@host01 ~]$ nroff
mktemp: cannot create temp file /tmp/man.n10337: Permission denied
/usr/bin/nroff: line 50: ${TMPFILE}: ambiguous redirect
XXX
XXX WARNING: old character encoding and/or character set
XXX
```

Now, I'm really stumped as to how that happened!  But anyway. . . .

Thank you for all of the good comments, folks!  You've helped me learn more about how man pages work.