# Showing all pages at once with man command

Tags: terminal, command, man

Say if I run the command `man who`, I have to keep pressing space or enter to show all content. Is there a way to show all of the content at once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use `man` without `less`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23394/23408)

Answer (score 9):

Pipe the output through `cat`:

```
man who | cat
```

This works because `man` (or actually `pager`, which is a symlink to `less`) will check to see what kind of terminal is connected to STDOUT.  If there is no terminal, i.e if STDOUT is redirected to a file or pipe, then there will be no attempt to format the text so that it can be interactively scrolled.

Comment: That's nice too, and the first thing I tried... but I couldn't find documentation guaranteeing that it would work. But as `man man` mentions, the default pager is `pager -s`, which is another name for `less`, and it is Well-Known that piping from `less` works just as one would expect. So this should be safe.

Comment: That's probably the most portable, followed by `PAGER=cat man who`. @dhag Note that man-db (the most common `man` implementation on Linux nowadays) at least does not spawn `less` when stdout is not a terminal. And `pager` does not have to be `less` (neither `pager` or `less` exist on some systems).

Comment: +1, DNUUOC (Definitely Not Useless Use Of Cat)

Answer (score 5):

Use `cat` as the pager; for example this will dump the entire manpage for command `ls`:

```
man -P cat ls
```

Note that this isn't portable (I only tried this on Debian and Mac OS systems); for example, on Ultrix or Tru64, [-P sets the manpath](http://www.polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=man&af=0&sf=0&of=Tru64&tf=2).

Comment: This is better than my answer because it takes out an unnecessary spawn of `less`

Comment: Good point, though it could be argued that your answer is better because it saves one from having to know about `-P`.

Comment: Not all `man` implementations have a `-P`. Or it may mean something else (like specifying a _manpath_ on Ultrix).

Comment: You learn something everyday! Thanks @StéphaneChazelas, I added your comment to the answer.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it's portable outside Linux (the two commonly found `man` implementations there derive from a common one that supports it) and FreeBSD and their derivatives (even other BSDs like NetBSD/OpenBSD don't support it).

Answer (score 3):

One age-old stunt:

```
man whatever | col -b > whatever.txt
```

Using the very obscure `col` command filters out all the weird backspaces and duplicate characters that `nroff` uses to do formatting. Then, you can use your choice of text editor to look over the entire man page.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a terminal emulator that supports scrolling back, and have set the size of the scrollback buffer to something "sufficently large", you can use that scrollback for navigating the output.

I would use

```
MANPAGER=cat man who
```

to write out all the man page text at once to the terminal (it's a variant of `man -P cat ls`).

I use `konsole` as terminal, which is set up to support scrolling using the mouse scroll wheel.
It works very well for this case - the wheel scrolls through the man page text, and entering any character jumps back to the prompt.
Using the keys <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>, you can scroll by terminal hight sections.

Other terminal emulators can be set up in a similar way.
As alternative, a terminal multiplexer like `tmux`/`screen` can be used to provide the scrollback buffer.

If you can not scroll up to the top of the man page, set the scrollback buffer size of your terminal emulator to a larger value.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you need to read manul `ls` :

```
man ls | sed  's/\n//g'
```

Comment: What do you think this accomplishes? By itself, `sed 's/\n//g'` is a pass-through; you might as well be saying `man whatever | cat`, which was already given.

Comment: You could use `man ls | tr -d '\n'` to do what that seems to intend, but that does not help with the question (and is not that useful in the first place).

Comment: Strictly speaking, this does achieve what the OP wants. Yes, it is needlessly complicated, yes it's the same as doing a non-action like `sed 's/./&/'`, but it does result in the whole man page being printed.